# Alternative to Nautilus for copying file paths?

Tags: nautilus, 20.04, filemanager, paths

I just moved from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. A strange behaviour in *Files* (*Nautilus*) is that you cannot copy a file path. Instead, it copies

```
x-special/nautilus-clipboard
copy
file:///home/mywork/test.txt
```

instead of

```
/home/mywork/test.txt
```

As I researched, this change has come into effect in 19.04. Several bugs have been filed for this behaviour. Therefore, I assume it is the intended behaviour.

Since I frequently copy files and run them in the terminal, I have to shift to another file manager.

I wanted to use *Nemo*, but I read the latest version has the same behaviour (apparently they use the same core system).

Can you recommend a file browser with the standard path copying behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other answers introduced various file managers, but I went for **Nemo** because it is pretty much similar to *Nautilus*. Contrary to what I had read, **Nemo 4.4.2** pastes the file location with no superfluous text.

*Nautilus* is indeed the worst thing I encountered in Ubuntu. And I faced a series of problems with it.

In a fresh installation of 20.04, I constantly get the error of

```
nautilus[3111]: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
```

apparently, because I do not have `net` command installed, and *Nautilus* does not understand it.

`tracker-miner-fs` constantly works because I have over 10 HDD archives connected to my computer, and it indexes the files I do not want to be indexed.

I went through a complicated process to effectively disable it.

The worse thing is that you cannot `uninstall` it without breaking the system.

Comment: I agree Nautilus is awful. One of the reasons I switched to LXDE. Pcmanfm has the essential context menu "copy path" option, use it all the time.

Comment: **Nemo** also has input filename prefix to focus item, which also discarded by **nautilus**. 
I turn to Nemo today.

Answer (score 4):

Copy from nautilus and then paste into a terminal by right-mouse "Paste as Filenames". This will preserve the path. This menu option appears only after copy. I have tested this on fresh installs of 19.10 and 20.04.

[image]

Comment: my right click on `gnome-terminal` does not give that option. Where should I find it?

Comment: this workaround worked, but also weird experience.  
  also not work in other application.

Answer (score 2):

For files paths copying/pasting you could use Caja or Thunar:

```
sudo apt install thunar caja
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I was aware of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. It just shows the path to the parent folder. I look for a quick way (as it was the case for years) to copy the script to run it in terminal. Does PCManFM-Qt allow a quick copy? Or I should come from the menu for each file?

Answer (score 0):

Install nautilus-open-terminal by typing in the terminal `$ sudo apt install nautilus-open-terminal` 
Log out and in again. 
You can follow exact instructions in the [following link](https://www.howtogeek.com/192865/how-to-open-terminal-to-a-specific-folder-in-ubuntus-file-browser/amp/)

Then In nautilus right click and select "open in terminal" then copy the directory from the terminal with "ctr + shft + c"

Comment: my right click in *Nautilus* does not give an option of *open in terminal*.

Comment: @Googlebot please review update

Answer (score 0):

Terminal file manager nnn can copy file paths to clipboard on selection. See the program option `-x`.

```
sudo apt install nnn
```

Answer (score -1):

The last version of `nautilus` copies only path, without unnecessary text.
Update `nautilus` with commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nautilus
```

You need version

```
nautilus/focal-updates,now 1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.1
```

from `focal-updates` repository.